# Compound Sentences with Interrupting Phrase

Tags: commas, compound-sentences, interrupting-phrase

If I have a compound sentence with two independent clauses joined by an "and", but also have an interrupting phrase, what is the rule on punctuation (assuming I only want to use commas, not em dashes or parentheses)?

Example:
Most of the people had arrived and as it was already late they had already begun to eat.

Without the interrupter, it would read:

> Most of the people had arrived, and they had already begun to eat.

However, my gut and experience tell me that with the interrupter, the comma should move to after the and:

> Most of the people had arrived and, as it was already late, they had already begun to eat.

However, I've seen commentary online that espoused putting commas completely around and:

> Most of the people had arrived, and, as it was already late, they had already begun to eat.

But this seems an excessive use of commas. I tend to believe the single comma after and is correct, and having the interrupter changes where the comma would go. But I'd like to know if anyone is aware if there is a CORRECT grammar rule for this, versus if it is just opinion or preference.

Comment: It’s between you and your style guide. Some say: *Most of the people had arrived and, as it was already late, they had already begun to eat.* Some say: *Most of the people had arrived, and as it was already late, they had already begun to eat.* Some, adhering to the strictest rule of using a comma before a coordinating conjunction and surrounding a nonessential clause with commas say: *Most of the people had arrived, and, as it was already late, they had already begun to eat.* I find the first most pleasing, and I think it matches my guide of choice (*Chicago*). I'll check.

Comment: There's no rule that says independent clauses _must_ be separated by commas: "Most of the people had arrived and they had already begun to eat" is fine. Generally, lighter punctuation is less jarring, so with your example I would prefer "Most of the people had arrived and, as it was already late, they had already begun to eat".

Comment: Thanks, all, for the commentary. Tinfoil, I also use Chicago as my guide of choice. From everyone's comments, it sounds like there is indeed no hard-and-fast rule, as all 3 approaches are acceptable. I too like the first for readability, and will stick with it for consistency.